# Protein is 4 kilocalories per gram. Does this value account for the thermic effect of food?

Tags: diet, nutrition, calories, protein, food

I have read that protein is actually 5 kcal/gram, and with the thermic effect of food, it becomes 4 kcal/gram.
But I have also read that protein is 4 kcal/gram, and with the thermic effect of food, it becomes 3.2 kcal/gram.
 Which is it?

Comment: USDA says 4kcal/gram

Comment: Welcome to the stack Regjohn, take the [tour] when you have a moment. Unfortunately, general nutrition questions are off topic here, unless they directly relate to exercise, voting to close.

Comment: See my [comments in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/324/the-locker-room)